# How to set MouseOver event/trigger for border in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I want the border to turn green when the mouse is over it and then to return to blue when the mouse is no longer over the border.

I attempted this without any luck:

```
<Border 
    Name="ClearButtonBorder" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    CornerRadius="0,3,3,0" 
    Background="Blue">
    <Border.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="Green" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="Blue" />
        </Trigger>
    </Border.Triggers>
    <TextBlock 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Text="X" />
</Border>
```

How can one set a trigger or events for MouseOver?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Yes, this is confusing...

According to [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20101001072702/http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/patl-closed/archive/2006/11/02/Using-Property-Triggers-on-a-UIElement.aspx), it looks like this is an omission from WPF.

To make it work you need to use a style:

```
    <Border Name="ClearButtonBorder" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="0,3,3,0">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="X" />
    </Border>
```

I guess this problem isn't that common as most people tend to factor out this sort of thing into a style, so it can be used on multiple controls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I know how it's done. Still, the reason why it has to be implemented like that remains illogical to me. But that's OK, I guess. :)

Comment: Yes, I agree it is illoigcal. As I say, seems to be a bug/omission from WPF.

Comment: I disagree that it's either a bug or an omission. In WPF there is  an explicit rule set defining property value precedence. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx

Comment: The blog post's link is dead

Comment: The link is dead, but https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx is not.

Comment: Interestingly this didn't work for me on a `CheckBox` but wrapping a `Border` around it helped.