# Event changed on combobox with datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

sample combobox (xaml):

```
<ComboBox Height="23" Name="status" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="120" SelectedItem="test">
</ComboBox>
```

how i can starting event click (etc...) or changed, on my combobox?

Comment: Here there is an example how to use EventTriggers in xaml: [How to set MouseOver event/trigger for border in XAML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388429/how-to-set-mouseover-event-trigger-for-border-in-xaml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add events for the mouse to the combobox by typing Mouse and seeing the options available. Here is an event you can add: **MouseDown="ComboBox_MouseDown"**

```
<ComboBox MouseDown="ComboBox_MouseDown" Height="23" Name="status" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="120" SelectedItem="test">
                                </ComboBox>
```

Then in the code behind add:

```
private void ComboBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Your code here
}
```