# Simple way to change appearance of a TextBlock on hover?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox

I'm making a zoom control (Slider) with a TextBlock indicator that tells you want the current scale factor is (kinda like in the bottom-right corner of Word).

I'm a couple days into learning WPF, and I've been able to figure out how to do most of it, but I get the sense there's a much simpler way (one which, perhaps, only involves XAML-side code rather than a bunch of mouse events being captures.

I'd like for a the text to be underlined when hovered over (to imply clickability) and for a click to reset the slider element to 1.0.

Here's what I have:

```
<StatusBarItem Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Slider x:Name="mapCanvasScaleSlider" Width="150" Value="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Minimum="0.25"  Maximum="4" TickPlacement="BottomRight" 
            Ticks="0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.5, 3, 4"/>
</StatusBarItem>
<StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
    <TextBlock Name="zoomIndicator" Text="{Binding ElementName=mapCanvasScaleSlider,Path=Value,StringFormat=0%}"
                MouseDown="ResetZoomWindow" MouseEnter="zoomIndicator_MouseEnter"  MouseLeave="zoomIndicator_MouseLeave"
                ToolTip="Zoom level; click to reset"/>
</StatusBarItem>
```

```
    private void ResetZoomWindow(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
    {
        mapCanvasScaleSlider.Value = 1.0;
    }

    private void zoomIndicator_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        zoomIndicator.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
    }

    private void zoomIndicator_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        zoomIndicator.TextDecorations = null;
    }
```

I feel as though there's a better way to do this through XAML rather than to have three separate .cs-side functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a style trigger for the text block, like described in this other post [How to set MouseOver event/trigger for border in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388429/how-to-set-mouseover-event-trigger-for-border-in-xaml)

Working solution:

```
<StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
    <TextBlock Name="zoomIndicator" Text="{Binding ElementName=mapCanvasScaleSlider,Path=Value,StringFormat=0%}"
                MouseDown="ResetZoomWindow" ToolTip="Zoom level; click to reset">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="TextBlock.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</StatusBarItem>
```

Still have to reset the zoom level manually (I think), though.

Comment: Seems to have done the trick.  Better yet, I didn't even need to use a border!  I'll edit your answer with the working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VisualState (if you're using Blend its easy to edit).
Personally I prefer style triggers, unless I have to add StoryBoard animation - then I offen use VisualState

[about VisualState](http://weblogs.asp.net/sergeyzwezdin/archive/2009/04/29/visualstatemanager-how-we-can-define-user-interface-in-wpf-and-sliverlight.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you wouldn't want to use a `TextBlock` as a button (although of course you can).  You may want to consider using a more appropriate control like `Button` or `HyperlinkButton`, which have the basic mouse event handling already wired up.  You can then apply whatever styles you like.  A `Button` control, for example, can be easily [styled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) re-templated as a `TextBlock` with underline on mouse-over:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="LinkButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.1">
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextDecorations">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <TextDecorationCollection>Underline</TextDecorationCollection>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="content" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Use it by referencing the style key:

```
<Button Content="click" Style="{StaticResource LinkButtonStyle}" />
```

Using this approach (rather than the alternative of adding triggers to a TextBlock) brings some advantages, which are built in to the Button control.

1. You can apply styles to compound states like `Pressed`
2. You can use the `Click` event, and its related `Command` property