# wpf - How can i control visibility on mousehover of usercontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a user control and I want to disable the visibility on a control within the UserControl. I only want it to be visible when the user's cursor is hovering over the main part of the user control which is the 'orange' rectangular part. The red circle is the part of the control which should only be visible on 'hover'

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas >
            <Canvas.Background>
                <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Stretch="Uniform" Viewport="20,20,20,20" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="sc#1,0.01,0.01,.01" Stroke="sc#1,0.02,0.02,.02" StrokeThickness="0.1"/>
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Canvas.Background>

            <local:ShapeNode Canvas.Left="117" Canvas.Top="84"/>
            <local:ShapeNode Canvas.Left="242" Canvas.Top="183"/>

        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**UserControl - ShapeNode.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.ShapeNode"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Fill="Red" Opacity=".2" Height="150" Width="150"></Ellipse>
        <Border Margin="5" Height="50" Width="100" Background="#FFDE6119" CornerRadius="5"></Border>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Text="Donuts" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Do you want to show the ellipse when Mouse is entered into Border?

Comment: With a trigger. Here's a mouse over trigger answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2388563/424129

Comment: Hey its my friend Ed again. Hey!  Only show ellipse when mouse is within rectangular bounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would rather use a control that can be templated within a UserControl. My favorite is a Button -- this is because of the click event if there is any use. But you can use other ones.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.ShapeNode"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" >
                <Ellipse x:Name="MyEllipse" Visibility="Hidden" Fill="Red" Opacity=".2" Height="150" Width="150"/>
                <Border Margin="5" Height="50" Width="100" Background="#FFDE6119" CornerRadius="5"></Border>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Text="Donuts" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger SourceName="MyGrid" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="MyEllipse" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
     </Button.Template>
  </Button>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `binding` to achieve your result. *Bind* the visibility property of ellipse to `Border` in *ShapeNode.xaml*

Set your `border` name to e.g. "border1" and put the visibility binding as:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, ElementName=border1, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibillityConverter}}"
```

You have to create a *converter* to change your boolean to *visibility*. 
Use the following converter:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        if (value is bool)
        {
            flag = (bool)value;
        }
        return (flag ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Please note that in your case you have to return *hidden* not *collapsed*. Otherwise your border changes position when visibility changes.

Comment: this is the cleanest solution imo

Answer (score 1):

> xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
>   xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1" Width="200" Margin="176,197,248,114" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment">
            <Ellipse Fill="Red" Opacity=".2" Height="150" Width="150" Margin="25,0,25,-19"/>
            <Border Margin="50,40.5" Height="50" Width="100" Background="#FFDE6119" CornerRadius="5"/>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Text="Donuts" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Grid1}" PropertyName="Visibility">
                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                            </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                        </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
```